# SQL Server a view built on a proc where I can change the parameters to underlying proc

Tags: sql-server

I have a proc that takes some parameters and returns a data table. I've built a view on top of that proc because many 3rd party reporting systems only let you connect to views or tables. My question is, is there any way to call the view and somehow pass parameters from the view to the underlying proc it's calling? Or what are the options with this?

```
create view MyView_Pizza_Pepsi
    select * from openquery(link, 'set no count on; exec MyProc "Pizza", "Pepsi" ')
```

So not right now I have to make a ton of hardcoded views with hardcoded params in order to pull this into the reporting tool. Not ideal.

Comment: A `VIEW` by design does not take parameters.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, NO, you can't pass parameter to the view. One alternative is to get all data and filter condition to the view itself like

```
create view MyView_Pizza_Pepsi
    select * from openquery(link, 'set no count on; exec MyProc')
    Where col1 = 'Pizza'
    and col2 = 'Pepsi';
```

Well, you need to change your procedure accordingly. Now, you can pass those parameter from your application and get the filtered data.

I would remove that openquery call all together and convert that to normal `SELECT` statement.

Comment: The proc is long running without the parameters to filter so that's why we were hoping to add them to the proc before it runs.

Comment: @user441521, then you don't need the view at all. Rather, your report builder have call the procedure directly and grant access to the procedure only. That way you will achieve what you are trying.

Comment: Many 3rd party reporting tools only allow connection to view/tables. That's the main issue.

Comment: @user441521, In that case, am afraid as I don't see any other option.